# How to fix NA error on the LAG LOG aggregated returns in R for FRED data

Tags: r, quantmod

I am having difficulty understanding why the `apply.quarterly()` function is not really giving me the quarterly returns and returning NA and why my `diff(log())` function is also not working with FRED data. Perhaps I am doing something wrong but I cannot really understand what.  Could someone help me understand or fix this issue?

**The code I use:**

```
library("quantmod")
#Getting FRED data exchange rate
setDefaults(getSymbols,src='FRED')
getSymbols('DEXNOUS')
#DEXNOUS <- as.data.frame(DEXNOUS)

#Getting SP500
getSymbols("^GSPC",src="yahoo")
GSPC <- as.data.frame(GSPC)

#Getting Brent blend oil
setDefaults(getSymbols,src='FRED')
getSymbols("POILBREUSDM",src = "FRED")
#POILBREUSDM <- as.data.frame(POILBREUSDM)

#Aggregating the data
GSPC_AVG_QUARTER<- apply.quarterly(GSPC,mean)

POILBREUSDM_AVG_QUARTER <- apply.quarterly(POILBREUSDM,mean)

DEXNOUS_AVG_QUARTER <- apply.quarterly(DEXNOUS,mean) #for some reason returning NA

#Calculating the log returns

n <- length(GSPC_AVG_QUARTER)
log_returns_GSPC_AVG_QUARTER <- diff(log(GSPC_AVG_QUARTER$GSPC.Adjusted))

ns <- length(POILBREUSDM_AVG_QUARTER)
log_returns_POILBREUSDM_AVG_QUARTER <- diff(log(POILBREUSDM_AVG_QUARTER)) 

nd <- length(DEXNOUS_AVG_QUARTER)
log_returns_DEXNOUS_AVG_QUARTER <- diff(log(DEXNOUS_AVG_QUARTER)) #na
```

**Snipet of the outcome for aggregated data:**

[image]

**Snipet of the outcome for diff Log returns:**

[image]

I would really appreciate it if someone could please help me out on this.

Note: I edited the code on 14/02/2022 22:28 CET on this post but I still get the error for the FRED data on the exchange rates.

Comment: `xts`-objects are not dataframes. They are R matrix-class. You should learn to make greater use of `str` and `class` when results are puzzling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make these changes:

- do not convert the xts objects to data frames
- suggest not using setDefaults
- n, ns and nd are not used and those lines are dropped.
- add na.rm = TRUE to mean
- use Ad(...) to extract the adjusted column
- have cleaned up formatting

This gives

```
library(quantmod)

getSymbols('DEXNOUS', src = 'FRED')
getSymbols("^GSPC", src = "yahoo")
getSymbols("POILBREUSDM", src = "FRED")

GSPC_AVG_QUARTER <- apply.quarterly(GSPC, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
POILBREUSDM_AVG_QUARTER <- apply.quarterly(POILBREUSDM, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
DEXNOUS_AVG_QUARTER <- apply.quarterly(DEXNOUS, mean, na.rm = TRUE)

log_returns_GSPC_AVG_QUARTER <- diff(log(Ad(GSPC_AVG_QUARTER)))
log_returns_POILBREUSDM_AVG_QUARTER <- diff(log(POILBREUSDM_AVG_QUARTER)) 
log_returns_DEXNOUS_AVG_QUARTER <- diff(log(DEXNOUS_AVG_QUARTER))

#######

head(log_returns_GSPC_AVG_QUARTER, 3)
##            GSPC.Adjusted
## 2007-03-30            NA
## 2007-06-29   0.049843241
## 2007-09-28  -0.005164808

head(log_returns_POILBREUSDM_AVG_QUARTER, 3)
##            POILBREUSDM
## 1990-03-01          NA
## 1990-06-01  -0.2181184
## 1990-09-01   0.5069333

head(log_returns_DEXNOUS_AVG_QUARTER, 3)
##                 DEXNOUS
## 1971-03-31           NA
## 1971-06-30 -0.003084078
## 1971-09-30 -0.015590386
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you helped me. Sorry for the silly mistakes made by me. I truly appreciate your support!